# Greedy heuristic using python

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty in getting my logic correct for my algorthim. Basically The algorithm starts with a single colour selected at random from the given list of colours, and then adds the nearest colour
(in terms of the Euclidean distance) not yet used to the end of the sequence
constructed so far-and then loops until all the colours have been appended.

small dataset rgb values

```
0.9664535356921388 0.4407325991753527 0.007491470058587191
0.9109759624491242 0.939268997363764 0.5822275730589491
0.6715634814879851 0.08393822683708396 0.7664809327917963
0.23680977536311776 0.030814021726609964 0.7887727172362835
0.3460889655971231 0.6232814750391685 0.6158156951036152
0.14855463870828756 0.18309064740993164 0.11441296968868764
0.014618780486909122 0.48675154060475834 0.9649015609162157
0.06456228097718608 0.5410881855511303 0.46589855900830957
0.6014634495610515 0.08892882999066232 0.5790026861873665
0.26958550381944824 0.5564325605562156 0.6446342341782827
0.48103637136651844 0.35523914744298335 0.249152121361209
0.9335154980423467 0.45338801947649354 0.5301612069115903
0.019299566309716853 0.5081019257797922 0.005780237417743139
```

algorithm so far

```
def greedy(cols):
    for i in range(0, len(cols)):
      firstchoice = random.choice(cols)
      dist = np.linalg.norm(firstchoice-cols[i])
      print(dist)
```

So my script reads in the colours correctly and then shows the representation in a graph. However the algorithm above is obviously wrong. I'm trying at the moment to print the distance between the random choice and then the rest of the colours (however since it's rgb values, it's leading me to be more confused). Furthermore i'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: What are you expecting `firstchoice-cols[i]` to do?

Comment: The error is straightforward. Your `cols[i]` is a python list and not a numpy array. I recommend adding `cols = np.array(cols)` as the first to the `greedy` function.

Comment: I'm expecting it to minus the rgb value from the randomly selected rgb value. I'm a newb at python and programming so i'm maybe a little wrong in my thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import OrderedDict
```

I suspect you have your data in a form like this:

```
rgb = np.array([[0.9664535356921388, 0.4407325991753527, 0.007491470058587191],
[0.9109759624491242, 0.939268997363764, 0.5822275730589491],
[0.6715634814879851, 0.08393822683708396, 0.7664809327917963],
[0.23680977536311776, 0.030814021726609964, 0.7887727172362835],
[0.3460889655971231, 0.6232814750391685, 0.6158156951036152],
[0.14855463870828756, 0.18309064740993164, 0.11441296968868764],
[0.014618780486909122, 0.48675154060475834, 0.9649015609162157],
[0.06456228097718608, 0.5410881855511303, 0.46589855900830957],
[0.6014634495610515, 0.08892882999066232, 0.5790026861873665],
[0.26958550381944824, 0.5564325605562156, 0.6446342341782827],
[0.48103637136651844, 0.35523914744298335, 0.249152121361209],
[0.9335154980423467, 0.45338801947649354, 0.5301612069115903],
[0.019299566309716853, 0.5081019257797922, 0.005780237417743139]])
```

Now let's redefine your function:

We need

- a `firstchoice`
- an ordered list of colours

So

```
def greedy(colours):
    firstchoice = random.choice(colours)
    distances = {np.linalg.norm(colour-firstchoice): colour for colour in colours}
    distances = OrderedDict(sorted(distances.items()))
    return distances
```

This takes your array as an input and assigns a distance to your `firstchoice` to each element of `colours`. Then I sort the dictionary an save it as an `OrderedDict` so that the order does not change.

You can now call:

```
res = greedy(rgb)
list(res.values())
```

and the receive the ordered list of values.

**EDIT** Here is the version without `OrderedDict`:

```
def greedy_without_ordereddict(colours):
    firstchoice = random.choice(colours)
    distances = {np.linalg.norm(colour-firstchoice): colour for colour in colours}
    ordered_keys = sorted(distances.keys())
    ordered_colours = [distances[key] for key in ordered_keys]
    return ordered_colours, ordered_keys
```

it sorts the keys of `distances` and then makes a list (which always remembers its ordering) of the values of `distances` (which are the RGB values) in the new order of the keys.

You could now for example call

```
rgbs, dists = greedy_without_ordereddict(rgb)
together = zip(rgbs,dists)
```

to have the colours and distances together. For example, this returns:

```
[(array([ 0.48103637,  0.35523915,  0.24915212]), 0.0),
 (array([ 0.14855464,  0.18309065,  0.11441297]), 0.39791185909505089),
 (array([ 0.60146345,  0.08892883,  0.57900269]), 0.44070995162369919),
 (array([ 0.34608897,  0.62328148,  0.6158157 ]), 0.47381395928847797),
 (array([ 0.2695855 ,  0.55643256,  0.64463423]), 0.4915245267784884),
 (array([ 0.06456228,  0.54108819,  0.46589856]), 0.50494509717795422),
 (array([ 0.9335155 ,  0.45338802,  0.53016121]), 0.54160563819132468),
 (array([ 0.01929957,  0.50810193,  0.00578024]), 0.54387294475741566),
 (array([ 0.96645354,  0.4407326 ,  0.00749147]), 0.54894337057573495),
 (array([ 0.67156348,  0.08393823,  0.76648093]), 0.61443784742562058),
 (array([ 0.23680978,  0.03081402,  0.78877272]), 0.67534337924056342),
 (array([ 0.91097596,  0.939269  ,  0.58222757]), 0.79804647364825909),
 (array([ 0.01461878,  0.48675154,  0.96490156]), 0.86437152825644481)]
```

Comment: Hey thankyou so much for the reply, the data set is just saved as a long list of rgb values. I tried using the answer however it was giving me the same error has i described above, on turning my dataset into a numpy array as suggested i get a strange error "TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')"

Comment: So you have your data in a txt or csv file? Then try `rgb = np.loadtxt("<YOURFILENAME>")`

Comment: This is giving me the same error, and yea the values are just in a txt file.

Comment: Well i just copied your data in a txt file and loaded it the same way and it threw no error, so maybe you have it formatted differently? Can you `print(rgb)`?

Comment: Hey i managed to get the thing working, there was a issue as you suggested with the formatting. One question, is there an alternative to using OrderedDict? just for my learning sake.

Comment: This was the first thing that came to my mind, but when i'm on PC later this evening I will see if I can find a way without `OrderedDict`. Normal dict is not sortable, that's the problem

Comment: Awesome, well there is no rush you've been a great help even without doing anything else. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem! That's what this site is made for ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for the revision it does work well but i'm having a few issues in adapting it to show the colours in my plotting function. Which is beyond the scope of this question. Again thanks so much,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just looking for the minimum distance and the next colour for your greedy algorithm some of the dictionary stuff might be overkill.  Something as simple as:

```
colours = np.array([[0.9664535356921388, 0.4407325991753527,   0.007491470058587191],
[0.9109759624491242, 0.939268997363764, 0.5822275730589491],
[0.6715634814879851, 0.08393822683708396, 0.7664809327917963],
[0.23680977536311776, 0.030814021726609964, 0.7887727172362835],
[0.3460889655971231, 0.6232814750391685, 0.6158156951036152],
[0.14855463870828756, 0.18309064740993164, 0.11441296968868764],
[0.014618780486909122, 0.48675154060475834, 0.9649015609162157],
[0.06456228097718608, 0.5410881855511303, 0.46589855900830957],
[0.6014634495610515, 0.08892882999066232, 0.5790026861873665],
[0.26958550381944824, 0.5564325605562156, 0.6446342341782827],
[0.48103637136651844, 0.35523914744298335, 0.249152121361209],
[0.9335154980423467, 0.45338801947649354, 0.5301612069115903],
[0.019299566309716853, 0.5081019257797922, 0.005780237417743139]])

choice = random.randint(0,colours.shape[0])
chosen = [choice]
while len(chosen) < colours.shape[0]:
    distances = [np.linalg.norm(colour-colours[choice]) for index,colour in enumerate(colours) if index not in chosen]
    choice = np.argmin(distances)
    chosen.append(choice)
```

could work for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, the colours.shape brings me an error of 
   choice = random.randint(0,colours.shape[0])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: @kraigthompson I was making the assumption that your colour data was in a numpy array.  I edited the answer to reflect that.  You would need to convert your data to this format but that shouldn't be very hard to do.  colours.shape[0] is just the number of colours in your list.